# Cast to byte: how do we clip figures

Tags: java

I'm reading Core Java by Horstmann.

This is an example:

```
    byte nx = (byte)300;
    System.out.println(nx);
```

The result is 44. I can't understand why? I suppose 2 variants: 1) everything is ruined and you just get a complete garbage; 2) there is some logic.

I'm inclined to the second variant as the book tells me that it is 44 that is received. So, there is some algorithm behind it.

Could you help me understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cast to `byte` will only retain the least significant 8 bits.  300 (as an `int` here) in binary is

```
00000000 00000000 00000001 00101100
```

Retaining the last 8 bits throws away the most signficant 1 (and everything else before it) which represents 256, so the remaining value is 300 - 256 = 44

```
00101100
```

Comment: Java uses signed bytes, so simply subtracting 256 won't work if the remainder is greater than 127.

Comment: @TedHopp Generally, you're right, the sign bit would throw it off if the sign bit of the remainder is set.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the binary expansion of 300:

> 100101100

Now chop off all but the last 8 bits (the width of a `byte` in Java):

> 00101100

Now convert that back to an integer value:

> 44

Note that you have to be careful about sign bits. You can't just take the remainder after dividing by 256. For instance:

```
byte nx = (byte)400;
System.out.println(nx);
```

will print -112 (not 144). That's because the bit pattern after the cast is

> 10010000

and the left-most (eighth) bit is treated as the sign bit in the two's complement representation of -112.

Answer (score 0):

The byte data type is only 8 bits long, and the decimal number 300 requires 9 bits. 
When you cast it, you truncated it and cut off the leftmost bit, leaving the binary representation of the decimal number 44.

If you need an analogy, think of casting from a float like 35.6 to an int. Because ints cannot have decimal places, that cast truncates '.6' off of the float, ignoring it completely in the returned value.

Comment: P.S. - 300 requires 9 _unsigned_ bits. Since Java has only signed numbers, 300 actually 10 _signed_ bits. The different doesn't matter in this case, as 00101100 and 0101100 have the same value, but it's important to know.